# Is it possible to select the last n items with nth-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using a standard list, I'm trying to select the last 2 list items. I've various permutations of `An+B` but nothing seems to select the last 2:

```
li:nth-child(n+2) {} /* selects from the second onwards */
li:nth-child(n-2) {} /* selects everything */
li:nth-child(-n+2) {} /* selects first two only */
li:nth-child(-n-2) {} /* selects nothing */
```

I'm aware of a new CSS3 selectors like `:nth-last-child()` but I'd prefer something that works in a few more browsers if possible (don't care about IE particularly).

Comment: IE notwithstanding, browser support for `:nth-last-child()` is about the same as `:nth-child()` [according to quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38). Also, `:nth-child()` and `:nth-last-child()` were both introduced in CSS3, neither is older or newer in that sense.

Comment: A lot of useful `nth-child` tricks are summarised by [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Comment: `https://caniuse.com/?search=nth-of-type` If you see the caniuse.com the `:nth-last-child` is not supported by all browsers, use the `nth-of-type(-n+2)`

Answer (score 391, accepted):

This will select the last two iems of a list:

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {color:red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
  <li>fred</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes but you're using `:nth-last-child()` which has already been mentioned.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, yes, nth-last-child was already mentioned, but not exactly how (-n+b) is a cool trick

Answer (score 59):

`nth-last-child` sounds like it was specifically designed to solve this problem, so I doubt whether there is a more compatible alternative. Support looks [pretty decent](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/), though.

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like nth-child support is actually the same as nth-last-child (I was sure IE8 supported nth-child but maybe not).

Answer (score 21):

`:nth-last-child(-n+2)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Because of the definition of the semantics of `nth-child`, I don't see how this is possible without including the length of the list of elements involved. The point of the semantics is to allow segregation of a bunch of child elements into repeating groups (*edit* - thanks BoltClock) or into a first part of some fixed length, followed by "the rest".  You sort-of want the opposite of that, which is what `nth-last-child` gives you.

Comment: With `:nth-child()` you can select the first `m` elements by specifying `:nth-child(-n+m)`.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm going to have to think on that for a sec ... oh, well yes you're right about that.  Clearly I'm not in much of a position to make a serious pronouncement on what the intention of the committee was when inventing CSS3 selectors anyway :-)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery in your project, or are willing to include it you can call `nth-last-child` through its selector API (this is this simulated it will cross browser). [Here is a link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-nth-last-child-plugin) to an `nth-last-child` plugin.  If you took this method of targeting the elements you were interested in:

```
$('ul li:nth-last-child(1)').addClass('last');
```

And then style again the `last` class instead of the `nth-child` or `nth-last-child` pseudo selectors, you will have a much more consistent cross browser experience.