# How do I choose the last 2 items in a list with css nth-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible? If not, is there a way to do it with jQuery?

Comment: no idea what this is asking. can you post example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to select the last n items with nth-child?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844456/is-it-possible-to-select-the-last-n-items-with-nth-child)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Unfortunately it's impossible.</strike>. Disregard this answer and [look at spliters answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6607613/2519416).

If it were to be possible, it would look something like...

```
ul li:last-child+li {...}
```

But this doesn't work, because + will select the immediate sibling *after* last-child (which is nothing, of course). There is no immediate *previous* selector.

There are different ways of achieving this with jQuery, the most performant would be...

```
var lastItems = $("#list li");
lastItems.slice(lastItems.length - 2).addClass("whatever");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qkzdJ/

Comment: It *is* possible. The spec and the duplicate question link have examples, albeit not with `:nth-child()` but with `:nth-last-child()`.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for this tip :) I didn't knew about it.

Comment: No, you can resolve it with CSS3:
`ul li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {}`

Answer (score 213):

It is possible with CSS3. Consider the markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">First item</a></li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pre-last item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

To choose the last two LI elements you do:

```
ul > li:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    background: green;
}
```

Works in all contemporary browsers including IE9, but excluding IE8 and below. To add support for those browsers, you might consider using [Selectivizr.js](http://selectivizr.com/)

Comment: @BoltClock It's also possible [with `nth-last-child`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/qVP8r/), but it's not going to be possible with `nth-child` because that selects from the start and the OP wants to select from the end.

Comment: Awesome job! I know its an old answer, but solved a little problem I had, so thanks!

Comment: This is nice as it avoids using jQuery to do something achievable via CSS

Comment: @BoltClock Regardless, it solves the OP's problem. It's obvious that nth-child isn't possible. OP probably suggested nth-child because he/she may not have been aware of last-of-type

Comment: @spliter best answer I've seen in a while stackoverflow, considering it's only 1 selector

Answer (score 32):

```
:last-child,
:nth-last-child(2) {
  ruleset
}
```

will play as well.

Answer (score 10):

For me it was this: 
`li:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))`