# Modify 2 last item on an ion-select

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-select` element and my last two items (configuration and pairing) should be buttons instead of radio buttons?

[image]

Here's the HTML

```
 <ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selectedUser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)" >
   <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user._id">
     <ion-content>{{ getUserName(user) }}</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Configuration</ion-option> 
     <ion-option>Pairing</ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

Comment: Is it only the visual aspect you want to change of configuration and pairing? Then I would advise you to check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604900/how-do-i-choose-the-last-2-items-in-a-list-with-css-nth-child
If you want to change the function of configuration and pairing shouldn't you change the HTML (if possible)?

Comment: @NickVanLoocke could you please more specific didn't know how to do it :/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
.select-popover .item:nth-last-child(-n+2){
  ion-radio{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Worked like a charm