# Style all elements except the last four

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I'd like to apply a style to all elements with the class thumbnail, except the last four.

This is my code so far.

```
.thumbnail:nth-child(){...}
```

Something goes in the nth-child() function but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to select the last n items with nth-child?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844456/is-it-possible-to-select-the-last-n-items-with-nth-child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sC2L5/

```
<style type="text/css">
.thumbnail {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:orange;
}

/* all the magic happens here*/
.thumbnail:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    background-color:red;
}

</style>


<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.thumbnail:not(:nth-last-child(-n + 4)) {
    /* .. */
}
```

But if you're trying to use `:nth-child()` to style children with a certain class, it won't work.

The `:nth-child()` pseudo class only styles **children** within a parent. It knows nothing about an elements class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well select the fith from last one and style any behind it : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sC2L5/1/)**

```
 .thumbnail:nth-last-child(5)~.thumbnail {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> .thumbnail:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
>       background-color:red;
>   }

its working 100%