# Advanced nth-child selection

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am attempting to figure out a nth-child selection rule that will select the "remainder" of division by three.  To explain here is a visual diagram.

EDIT: Providing more examples for clarity.

```
div1
(should select div1)

div1     div2
(should select div1 and div2)

div1     div2     div3
(should select nothing)

div1     div2     div3    div4
(should select div4)

div1     div2     div3    div4    div5
(should select div4 and div5)

div1     div2     div3     div4     div5     div6
(should not select anything)

div1     div2     div3     div4     div5     div6     div7
(should select div7)
```

etc...

I believe that this may be possible, but am unable to figure it out.

Comment: At least try and show some minimal effort toward how you have tried to solve this. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Can this be done with nth child? I am curious to see if anyone can come up with anything

Comment: It can, sort of - [**nth-last-child**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844456/is-it-possible-to-select-the-last-n-items-with-nth-child?rq=1)- [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XJhF/)..just not quite.

Comment: Boom http://jsfiddle.net/7XJhF/3/

Comment: I believe I have solved it to my satisfaction, despite having to write two different groupings of css

http://jsfiddle.net/MY4cD/

Comment: @user3590712 then answer your own question and mark it correct so future users can see it

Comment: I cannot do that yet as not enough time has passed for someone of my reputation to answer their own question (8 hour minimum).  I will do so as soon as possible though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child), and the [general sibling selector (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) can be combined to match elements following the last group of 3.

```
div:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n+3) ~ div {
    /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akzzM/

With the 3rd example of 7 divs:

- `nth-child(3n)` matches every 3rd `<div>` -- matching `3` and `6`.
- `nth-last-child(-n+3)` matches the last 3 siblings -- matching `5`, `6`, and `7`.
- Combined, they'll only match the last interval of 3 -- matching `6`.

Then `~ div` matches any siblings that follow (`7`).

---

To match the 1st and 2nd when there isn't a 3rd, you can also match the `:first-child` if it's one of the last 2 and `:last-child` if it's one of the first 2:

```
div:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n+3) ~ div,
div:first-child:nth-last-child(-n+2),
div:last-child:nth-child(-n+2) {
    /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JEST3/

Comment: I really like this solution, but does not quite work if you have only 1 or 2 elements.  I apologize if OP did not make that clear.

Comment: Great work. I was going to suggest `:only-child` but realized that it's already covered by both `:first-child:nth-last-child(-n+2)` and its counterpart and would therefore be superfluous.

Comment: you're amazing! great work~

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no single selector that will let you do this.

However a combination of `nth-last-child` and an overide with `nth-child` will get you there.

**CSS**

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {color:red;}

li:nth-child(3n) {color:black;}

li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(3) {color:black;}
```

**[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7XJhF/8/)**

Comment: O, this does not work if there are only 3 items but can be fixed http://jsfiddle.net/7XJhF/6/

Comment: It's not supposed to is it? It thought it was implicit that there would always be more than 3 divs otherwise what's the point?

Comment: OP mentions `div1 div2 div3 (should not select anything)` not that it's a hard fix from what you have so far

Comment: Edited...It's a little more readable that the `:not` solutions, I think.

Comment: I have updated my OP to reflect the intended functionality, this isn't quite the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the solution for your problem:

```
div:not(:nth-child(3n)):not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    background-color: #38f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved it to my satisfaction, despite having to write two different groupings of css.  The trick is that you can use multiple selectors in the same line, which is the equivalent of making Unions between the set selections.

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/MY4cD/

**A more complete solution (and expandable to other multiples besides three is below.**

Given the following HTML ( and for any number of  )

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

**The following CSS would create rows of three with the "remainder" divs highlighted red.**

```
    .cell {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(1){
        background:red;
    }

    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2){
        background:red;
    }

    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(3n+2):nth-last-child(1){
        background:red;
    }
```

**If you wanted to have 4 divs per row and select the remainder again you could use the following CSS**

```
    .cell {
        width: 25%;
    }

    /* accounts for when there is 1 remainder */
    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(1){
        background:red;
    }

    /* accounts for the first of 2 remainders */         
    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(2){
        background:red;
    }

    /* accounts for the second of 2 remainders */
    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(4n+2):nth-last-child(1){
        background:red;
    }

    /* accounts for the first of 3 remaidners */
    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(3){
        background:red;
    }

    /* accounts for the second of 3 remainders */
    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(4n+2):nth-last-child(2){
        background:red;
    }

    /* accounts for the third of 3 remainders */
    .cell:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(4n+3):nth-last-child(1){
        background:red;
    }
```

In this way, you can see the pattern will grow ever more complex the higher you go, but it is certainly possible for any number.

I have used this pattern along with media queries to simulate the effects of the new CSS flex-flow: row wrap; command with using floats for cross browser compatability.  You can see the full demo of this here : http://codepen.io/msorrentino/full/chHnu/

Comment: While valid, this is still quite verbose compared to Jonathan Lonowski's answer IMO (even if you condense all the declaration blocks to a single one by grouping the selectors with commas).