# How to center the last item in ng repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to create elements.
I have used: `nth-child(4n+1)` to display only 4 elements in a row but I want the last div elements to be center aligned.
Is there any way to accomplish that in Angular?
Suppose there are 9 elements, I want to display the 9th element in the center.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container " ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row LaunchTrackerBrands text-center" >
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 Brandtracker" ng-repeat="data in LauncherData">
      <div class="BrandName " title="{{data.Brand}}" >
        <img src={{data.src}} draggable="false" text-center/>
         <div class="Metaname">
            <div class="inner-triangle" style="border-left: {{data.color}} 30px solid"></div>
            {{data.name}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

.LaunchTrackerBrands {
    margin-top: 5em;
}

.Brandtracker {
    margin-left: 2em
}

.LaunchTrackerBrands :nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}

.BrandName {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

    .BrandName a img {
        padding: 0.5em;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

.Metaname {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-triangle {
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: Angular doesn't provide any such functionality. Are you using bootstrap, materialize or something?

Comment: You could just use css to have a specific style for the last child : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: I  am using bootstrap @Abinthaha

Comment: If i have 10 children i want 2 of them to be centered @ibenjelloun

Comment: @ShubhamMundhra Which version of bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to select the last n items with nth-child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844456/is-it-possible-to-select-the-last-n-items-with-nth-child)

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: Be precise : you want *the last item of a row* to be centered, or you want *the last item of your collection* to be centered ?

Comment: There is a possible way to do this within the ng-repeat, I'll try it out...

Comment: Last item of my collections @trichetriche

Comment: Oh that's Angular JS, sorry I thought this was Angular.

Comment: I'll made an example below with ´$index´, ´ng-class´ and ´length´, for me it works...

Answer (score 4):

Try this out,

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 Brandtracker"
     ng-repeat="data in LauncherData"
     ng-class="{'alignCenter':$last}">
</div>
```

where `alignCenter` be the class that aligns your element to center.

Comment: Never saw $last, awesome solution!

Comment: By using $last i can access only the last element but i want to access the second last element also @georgeawg

Comment: @ShubhamMundhra so do you want to center align the second last element too?

Comment: Yes i want to access the second last element also @chinmayan

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do is follow: In the save the current `index` in the `ng-repeat` with `$index`. Than use `ng-class` to check, if the current index is the same as the `length` of the looped list, so it is the last item in every case. If the condition is true, add a `class` which centers the element.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myList = [{
      id: 0,
      text: "item 1"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "item 2"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "item 3 (last one)"
    }
  ];

  $scope.myList2 = [{
      id: 0,
      text: "item 1"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "item 2"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "item 3"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "item 4"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text: "item 5 (last one)"
    }
  ];
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list--centered {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" class="wrapper">
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="item in myList" ng-init="idx = $index" ng-class="myList.length == idx + 1 ? 'list--centered' : ''">
    <span class="list__item">{{item.text}}{{idx}}</span>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="item in myList2" ng-init="idx = $index" ng-class="myList2.length == idx + 1 ? 'list--centered' : ''">
    <span class="list__item">{{item.text}}{{idx}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there are 2 or 3 elements @mrbuggy

Comment: @ShubhamMundhra I still works, because he takes in every case the length of the list and checks in ever iteration if the current item is the last one by using the length and the index + 1. So if you have 3 items in the list, length = 3 and the index + 1 of the last item would be 3 and then it adds the class for centering. So if you have for example 21 items the length would be 21 and the index + 1 of the last item would also be 21 and than it adds again the class for centering. In every case only for the last one. Take a look on my edited example

Comment: @ShubhamMundhra I edited the answer with two lists with a different count of items. Was this your question?

Comment: This solution apply's  css to all the last  3  ng-repeat elements but i want to apply css only if the fall in the next row(a row of  4) @MrBuggy