# If there is more then 3 li hide the rest and append html JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have scores of list items and I would like to only show the first 3.

Then on click of a button, I would like to show the hidden items. I initially set this to cap the number of characters and this works fine, however, this stops halfway through words so it is better for this project if I just hide the whole words over the maximum amount.

I get the error jQuery(...).length is not a function.

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var maxL = 3;
    var listItems = jQuery('.outer-card-expand li');
    jQuery(listItems).each(function () {
        
        var list = jQuery(listItems).length();
        if(list.length > maxL) {
            
            var begin = list.substr(0, maxL),
                end = list.substr(maxL);

            jQuery(this).html(begin + '<span class="dots">...</span>')
                .append(jQuery('<div class="see-more see-more-closed">').html(''))
                .append(jQuery('<span class="hidden text-thats-hidden">').html(end))
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
   display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-card-expand">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jamiec - I have updated my code.

Comment: You're looking for either `.length` (no parentheses) or `.size()` both of which will give you the same number

Comment: its `.length` not `.length()`

Comment: Your recent edit now changes the error message from what you said you had to a totally different one.

Comment: @jamiec, I just re-named the variables so they were easier to understand.

Comment: You really should make full [mre], also what this question is about? Of showing only first 3 list items, or cropping the content of them? Also one more time: its `.length` not `.length()` THIS will remove your current error, the one you are talking about in question . Be more clear, add content and be clear about desired behavior and result.

Comment: @ikiK I have found a simpler way to do this, but how do I get this by the class mentioned above instead of by UL? 

 jQuery("ul.items li:gt(4)").hide();

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var maxL = 3;
  //set you number to show
  var listItems = jQuery('.outer-card-expand li').length;
  // get curent number of items
  if (listItems > maxL) {
    // if curent number is biger then wanted
    jQuery('.outer-card-expand li:nth-child(+n+' + (maxL + 1) + ')').addClass("hidden")
    //find all li items after set crop number
    jQuery('<li><span class="dots">...CLICK</span></li>').insertAfter(jQuery('.outer-card-expand li:last-child'));
    //add span with dots or whatever
  }

});


jQuery(document).on("click", ".dots", function() {
  // on click of dots remove hidden class and remove dots parent li element
  jQuery('.outer-card-expand').find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden")
  jQuery('.outer-card-expand').find(".dots").parent("li").remove()
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-card-expand">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Read here to see how CSS selectors in example works:

[Is it possible to select the last n items with nth-child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844456/is-it-possible-to-select-the-last-n-items-with-nth-child)

Comment: Thank you, this works well. How do I but the insertafter after the last child though? li:nth-last-child(' ')' ?

Comment: Selector for last child is literary:  `li:last-child` I changed the snippet @EmmaKitching

Comment: legend! awesome thank you. Yea the 'button' being at the end after all the list items is better.

Comment: I have added a toggle function to this here if you would like to add it to your answer, or do I create a new answer?  
jQuery(document).on('click', '.see-more', function () {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('see-more-open');
  jQuery(this).siblings('.list-item-overflow').toggleClass('hidden');
 });

Comment: It does not really matter ;) Question was how to crop the list based on current length, This was one of the solutions, people can do there's own logic from here and expand based on there's specific needs. ;) Glad it helped. @EmmaKitching

Comment: @EmmaKitching BTW people here other then just out of fun "work" here also for points  so if some of the answers solved your problem please mark some answer you wish to accept  on ✔︎ button. Also it helps others too see it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to add add direct hidden class to extra li after the max ,

and apppend div to show others , without doing extra loop, wrap ..

use the `gt` expression   => `li:gt(${maxL-1})`

use selector after condition :

```
if(listItems.length > maxL) {
   $(`.outer-card-expand li:gt(${maxL-1})`).hide()
}
```

See below example snippet :

```js
$(function () {
    var maxL = 3;
    var listItems = $('.outer-card-expand li');
    
    $(document).on("click",".see-more-closed", function(e){
       $('.outer-card-expand li').show(300);
       $(this).hide();
    })
    
    if(listItems.length > maxL) {
     $(`.outer-card-expand li:gt(${maxL-1})`).hide();
     
     $('.outer-card-expand ul').append('<div class="see-more see-more-closed">')
     
     
    }
    
});
```

```css
.see-more-closed:after {
  content:"more >";
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-card-expand">
  <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, your snippet works perfectly for what I need. I have one issue though, in my actual code there is a 'ul' outside of the 'li's and this conflicts with the code. I do not know why, but even when I add this to the snippet the js no longer works. How would I add the ul to this? Or is it easier if I find the ul and just add the class to it?

Comment: @EmmaKitching , it would work fine , as I've edited my asnwer , could you post real html to test it here