# Is there any way to select or target the last three lists? I have tried using child selector, but it allows only one element at a time to select

Tags: html, css

How to target the last 3 lists together? I have tried using child selectors, but it allows us to target only one element simultaneously.

[image: How to target the last 3 lists together? I have tried using child selectors, but it allows to target only one element at a time.]

Comment: Why did you choose *not* to post code when that would have been faster, easier and useful to those that may have been willing to help? *Pictures* of code are utterly pointless, inaccessible to those with visual impairments and can't be searched. Not to mention that it's a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844456/is-it-possible-to-select-the-last-n-items-with-nth-child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div > li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

</div>
```

Comment: here -n denotes that it has to select items from bottom?

Comment: if i understood your question correctly, yes it does.